# Not able to import Python module

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, python-module, falconframework

I am having a server and a testing module in falcon but I am not able to import the server module into the testing module when running the test cases.

This is my hierarchy:

```
project
   |
    --__init__.py
    --server.py
   |
     /tests
        |
          --__init__.py
          -- apitest.py
```

This is my testing code

```
"""
Unit test for Ping api resource
"""

from falcon import testing
import pytest
import server

@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def client():
    return testing.TestClient(server.api)

def test_get_message(client):
    result = client.simulate_get('/api/ping')
    assert result.status_code == 200
```

But when i run it it shows:

```
Traceback:
apiTest.py:7: in <module>
    import server
E   ImportError: No module named 'server'
```

What am I doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

Python checks for the module only in the current path of the script, which in your case is `/tests`. You would need to add `/project` to your path as well. The following code snippet should work:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("../")

import server
```

Comment: Yeah, that’s not a best practice since if you are going to want import module from other “depth” you will need to use this method every time for each path

Comment: I there a better way to do this instead of sys.path.append?
The sys.path.append is working fine.

Comment: The relative `../` path is taken from the location where the script is executed, not the absolute path of the file. This means it would break unless the cwd of the shell executing it is `tests/`. You can take a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56383447/6698642) on a similar question to make the paths absolute.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to set the add your project directory to the PYTHONPATH or put your project inside a directory that is already added. This lets python to use your package.

You can add the directory using `set`command on `cmd`. For example if you want to add `C:\Python` use command `set PYTHONPATH = C:\Python`

Now to import `server.py` you have to type `import project.server` or `from project import server`.

If you type `import project.server`, to use a function in server you will have to type in `project.server.<fuction>()` and if you used `from project import server` you will have to use `server.<function>()`.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to make your package installable, rather then fiddle with the PYTHONPATH. See guidelines to python packaging here: https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/